# The existence of a subsequence of harmonic functions that converges pointwise

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, convergence-divergence

Let $u_{n}$ be a family of harmonic functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and there exists a point $x_{0}$ such that $\{u_{n}(x_{0})\}$ is bounded. Then does it exist a subsequence of $u_{n}$  that converges pintwise?

First, we can choose compact subsets $\{K_j\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that $\cup{K_j}=\mathbb{R}^n$ ,and $K_j\subset K_{j+1}$, then we can restrict to every compact set $\{K_j\}$ and use the diagonal argument. And if we have every $u_n$ is nonegative, we can use Harnack inequality to obtain uniform boundedness and  $u_n$ is equicontinuous by the gradient estimates, therefore we can apply Arzelà–Ascoli  theorem. But for general case, I haven't got it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $f_n(x_1,\ldots,x_k)=nx_1$ on $\mathbb{R}^k$. These are harmonic and $\{f_n(0)=0\}$ is bounded. But they don't admit any pointwise convergent subsequence.